# Is it possible to 'tag' an airflow DAG in the UI?

Tags: airflow

In the airflow DAG UI, I'd like to add a tag for a subset of DAGs. Let's say there is a tag `#weekend_runs` that I'd like to add to some specific DAGs.

Is it possible to filter your view of DAGs in the UI based on tags in Airflow? Or do I need to do something hacky like add `_weekend_run` to the end of DAG names in order to use fuzzy search and filter out other scripts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding a **tag** to a DAG is now possible from Airflow 1.10.9

In order to filter DAGs (e.g by team), you can add tags in each dag.
The filter is saved in a cookie and can be reset by the reset button.

For example:

**Dag File**:

```py
dag = DAG('dag', tags=['example'])
```

**UI**:
[image: Dag Tag]

Note: This feature is only available for the RBAC UI (enabled using `rbac=True` in `[webserver]` section in your `airflow.cfg`).

Comment: Hi, i dont know if this should be a separate question. But as i tried this filter tags feature, if I want to filter more than one tags, then it will have the effect of OR instead of AND. Do you know how to change it to and?

Comment: @SillySally It's currently not supported, I would suggest you open a feature request.

Comment: I saw something weird, this feature is on master branch, but not in any release 
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.12/airflow/www/templates/airflow/dags.html
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/templates/airflow/dags.html

Comment: It is on Release branch too, the link you are checking is for non-RBAC (old) UI, check: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.12/airflow/www_rbac/templates/airflow/dags.html

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible yet and it's not even in the [roadmap](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Airflow+2.0) for Airflow 2.0.
A hack I used in the past is to abuse of one of the fields (`DAG` name or `Owner`), as you suggested, for example by adding `_weekend_run` to the DAG name. And then I created a [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) userscript that allows to filter out the DAGs you don't want to show in the UI. Something along the line of the following script will do the job for your application:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Only weekend runs
// @match        http://<airflow-instance-url-here>/admin/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('td:not:contains("weekend_run")').parent().hide();
})();
```

Unfortunately for this to work it needs to be installed on each user's browser, which is far from ideal. Of course, the ideal thing would be to make a PR to the Airflow project :)